# What's the difference between these two selectors?

Tags: jquery

```
$(this).parents('table:first > tbody > tr')
```

And

```
$(this).parents('table:first').children('tbody').children('tr')
```

Comment: use closest rather than parents & :first

Comment: @redsquare: We don't know what he's actually trying to select.

Comment: closest == parents('table:first')

Comment: so I was saying you should always use closest over parents and a :first....regardless of what he is trying to select

Comment: My point was that he might actually be trying to do something entirely different.  You are correct, though.

Comment: @redsquare,closest can also be the children,so it's wrong,isn't it?

Comment: why not take a walk to the docs to reveal all....http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/closest

Comment: @redsquare,you are right,thank you!But I still haven't seen the difference yet...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The difference is that the first selector is entirely within the `parents` call, whereas the second one isn't.

Therefore, the first one looks for all parents of `this` which match `table:first > tbody > tr`.  (In other words, a `tr` containing `this` that is in the first `table`)

The second one will find the parent of `this` which matches `table:first`, then find all of the `tr`s directly within `tbody`s of that parent. (In other words, all of the `tr`s directly inside the parent table)

Comment: Seems counter intuitive. I read the first exactly as the second. Of course I am too lazy to test.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: Read them more carefully.  You'll see what I mean.

Comment: I still don't see the difference based on your explanation,though I've stepped into this issue myself..

Comment: Read more carefully.  Also, look at the elements matched in the intermediary objects created by the second line (`$(this).parents('table:first')` and `$(this).parents('table:first').children('tbody')`)

Comment: Doesn't " > tr" also mean "directly inside"?

Comment: Yes, but it's in the wrong place.  When you put it inside the `parents` call, it looks for parents that match that selector (parents that are `tr`s).  

When you call `children`, it looks for children of the element you already found.  (all children of the `table` that was returned by the `parents` call).

Comment: Oh I got it now,by your "(parents that are `tr`s)."

Answer (score 4):

Maybe an example will help... start out with this HTML

```
<table border=1>
 <thead>
  <th>Outter Table</th>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <table border=1 width=100>
     <thead>
      <th>Inner Table</th>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr><td>2a</td></tr>
      <tr><td class="test">2b</td></tr>
      <tr><td>2c</td></tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td>3</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Apply this script:

```
$('.test').parents('table:first > tbody > tr').addClass('foo');
$('.test').parents('table:first').children('tbody').children('tr').addClass('bar');
```

Result:

```
<table border="1">
 <thead>
  <th>Outter Table</th>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr class="foo"><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr class="foo">
   <td>
    <table width="100" border="1">
     <thead>
      <th>Inner Table</th>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr class="bar"><td>2a</td></tr>
      <tr class="bar"><td class="test">2b</td></tr>
      <tr class="bar"><td>2c</td></tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="foo"><td>3</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```