# jquery: children() vs child selector ">"

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, children

I have a table that has a section similar to the following:

```
<tr>
    <td> <span class="myclass"></span>
    </td>
<tr>
```

my $(this) is set to the tr element and I'm trying to access the Span elements that have the "myclass" class set.
The following seems to work:

```
if ($(this).children('td').children('span').is('.myclass')){
    alert('in here');
}
```

but when trying to use this:

```
if ($(this).children("td > span").is('.myclass')){
```

or this:

```
if ($(this).children("td span").is('.myclass')){
```

It does not.  I thought that either of the above 2 would come up with similar results (albeit through different methods) but apparently not.

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`children(selector)` will only match those children that match `selector`. None of `tr`'s children (the `td`s) can match `td > span`, as `tr` has has no `span` child elements, only `td`s and `td > span !== td`.

The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/children/) is also quite clear about this:

> Get the children of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

---

What you might want instead is [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$(this).find("td > span")
```

It returns **all descendants**, not just children, that match the selector.

Answer (score 1):

From the jQuery docs:

"The .find() and .children() methods are similar, except that the latter only travels a single level down the DOM tree."

I'd recommend using this:

```
if ($(this).find('.myclass').length){
    alert('in here');
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I explained this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864241/whats-the-difference-between-these-two-selectors).

The difference is that the first selector is entirely within the `children` call, whereas the second one isn't.

Therefore, the first one looks for all children of `this` which also match `td > span`. (In other words, all **{** `<span>`s children of `<td>`s **}** (the selector) that are themselves directly children of `this`)

The second one will find all `<td>` children of `this`, then find all of the `<span>`s in those `<td>`s.